# Joomla editor strips tags

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to create a custom component in Joomla 2.5 and struggling to get it to stop it stripping all html tags out of the editor field - links, new lines, p tags - the full works. The form field is below:

```
<field
    name="post"
    type="editor"
    label="COM_HELLO_WORLD_EDITOR_LABEL"
    description="COM_HELLO_WORLD_EDITOR_DESC"
    class="inputbox"
    filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"
    required="true"
    default=""
/>
```

Clearly there are many many posts about this around both SO and Joomla forums. However they generally seem to have two clear themes.

1. Tiny MCE Settings. I've checked after setting my default editor to "None" (i.e. just a text area) and the tags are all still stripped
2. Joomla Text filter settings. I'm logged in as a Global Admin with the super users set to "no filtering"

I'm overriding the model's save function for this with:

```
function store()
{
    $row =& $this->getTable();
    $input = new JInput();
    $data = $input->getArray($_POST);

    //Sets Users id as current logged in user if not set
    if(!$data['jform']['post_user']) {
        $data['jform']['post_user']=JFactory::getUser()->id;
    }

    // Bind the form fields to the post table
    if (!$row->bind($data['jform'])) {
        $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure the hello is valid
    if (!$row->check()) {
        $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }

    // Store the hello table to the database
    if (!$row->store()) {
        $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My gut instinct is that it's to do with JInput stripping HTML tags. But even adding in the extra line into the save file `$data['jform']['post']=$input->getHTML('post');` nothing happened. So I'm not really sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify an issue quickly - I want to use the preset Joomla 'Text Filter' Settings under 'Global Configuration' rather than manually setting each tag in the component!

---

**UPDATE 2**

I added filter="raw" to the editor form field. I now see the html `<p>` tags when I dump out the variable `$_POST['jform']['post'], null, 'HTML')`. However then when applying just a simple JInput Filter function - let alone applying the Joomla Config values - I'm getting null.

```
    $input = new JInput();
    $data = $input->getArray($_POST);
    $data['jform']['post']=$input->get($_POST['jform']['post'], null, 'HTML');
```

Is the sentence [here](http://developer.joomla.org/manual/chap-Joomla_Platform_Manual-Input.html) "HTML - Returns a string with HTML entities and tags intact, subject to the white or black lists in the filter." describing the JInput HTML filter referring to the Global Config Text filter settings? Just to confirm?

Comment: you don't want any filtering at all or?

Comment: Well I'd like to have the Joomla filtering system - as specified in the Text Filters area of Global Configuration. So for superadmins - no filtering. For some no html and for others selected HTML. But for me as a super admin no filtering yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
$input_options = JFilterInput::getInstance(
        array(
            'img','p','a','u','i','b','strong','span','div','ul','li','ol','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5',
            'table','tr','td','th','tbody','theader','tfooter','br'
        ),
        array(
            'src','width','height','alt','style','href','rel','target','align','valign','border','cellpading',
            'cellspacing','title','id','class'
        )
    );

    $postData = new JInput($_POST,array('filter' => $input_options));
```

First array it is allowed tags, second array it is allowed attributes.

Comment: Thanks for this :) However I was hoping to apply the default Joomla text filters as defined in Global Permissions - sorry I should have made this clearer in my question!

Answer (score 0):

What is this about? filter="JComponentHelper::filterText"? Did you write a custom filter?

The default filtering like most things in Joomla (also acl for example) is very strict so that if you get xss from not filtering it's a deliberate choice you've made not a security risk in the core. But your core filtering should be being applied ... except that you seem to have perhaps overridden with the unknown filter. So I suspect given this unknown filter it's falling back to very string.

Comment: No. I was under the impression that this applied the Joomla filters set in Global Config. I found this string in all the default Joomla components. And the API here http://api.joomla.org/11.4/Joomla-Platform/Application/JComponentHelper.html#filterText suggests that it "Applies the global text filters to arbitrary text as per settings for current user groups" which I took to mean that it applied the ACL settings from the 'Text Filter' settings in 'Global Configuration'

Comment: I did also try using `filter="safehtml"` which I saw in the docs page here: http://docs.joomla.org/Editor_form_field_type without any success as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes but no as part of your xml I don't think. If you look in JFilterInput and JForm you will see the list of available filters. JForm adds some to the basica JFilerInput list.

Comment: OK that kind of makes sense - I'll try this later when I get back to my computer. Related then. Where is this extra filter of `JComponentHelper::filterText` being defined in com_weblinks/com_content/com_cateogries etc being defined then? Do I need any filter at all in the xml then? Because I assume leaving it blank will also lead to filtering of html elements (the docs for joomla editor field says "filter (optional) allow the system to save certain html tags or raw data." which suggests it strips tags by default.

Comment: Yes it is aggressive by default, you can go as far as filter="raw" but there are a number of other options.  safehtml is pretty aggressive too, it's limited to the kinds of tags you usually see in commenting systems .. like p, ul, etc but definitely not spans, divs or iframes.

Comment: Was just looking and `JComponentHelper::filterText` seems to take the filter from the global config - having briefly looked through the intial platform pull for it here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/pull/641 Any thoughts? As I can't see it defined in com_weblinks/com_content/com_cateogries etc. Will try filter="raw" and using JFilterInput tonight :)

Comment: Added an update to my post to show where I've got to tonight! Any thoughts @Elin ? Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: HTML - Returns a string with HTML entities and tags intact, subject to the white or black lists in the filter.   YEs that should be using the black list and whitelist filters from the global configuration and it should be by group

Comment: Brilliant! Any idea why its giving off `null` then (the default value) - I've checked and `$_POST['jform']['post']` definitely exists. But then  `$data['jform']['post']` is giving `null` every time :/

Comment: You're dumping this out in the save method?

Comment: Yes. Same save method as above except underneath `$data = $input->getArray($_POST);` I've added in the extra line `$data['jform']['post']=$input->get($_POST['jform']['post'], null, 'HTML');` then used JDump to print out `$_POST['jform']['post']` and `$data['jform']['post']`

Answer (score 0):

Quite some time later, but just for the record, for anyone encountering the same problem, here my solution.

For me this problem was immediately solved by using JRequest instead of JInput. I believe it's deprecated, but it is still used by Joomla 2.5.14 (most up-to-date Joomla 2.5 at this moment) in the save() function of JControllerForm.